# mysql_fetch_array(), is not work in my program

Tags: php, html, mysql

i need to fetch multiple row or single row from mysql table,  but my code retrieve data from table only multiple rows as given in my where clause condition is true, not fetch single row  even my condition is true. plz suggest me anyone.  (i know only little bit english)

```
<?php 
include 'connection/db_connection.php';

 $sqlquery=mysql_query("select * from sadmin_invoiceno order by sno desc");
 $row1=mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlquery);
    $invoice=$row1['invoice_no'];
    /* if($row1['invoice_no']<=9)
    {
    $myvalue=$row1['invoice_no'];
    $idvalue="".$myvalue;   
    }
    if($row1['invoice_no']>9 && $row1['sno']<100)
    {
    $myvalue=$row1['invoice_no'];
    $idvalue="".$myvalue;   
    } */
        $sql="SELECT * FROM sadmin_sales where invoice_no='".$invoice."'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        $count=mysql_num_rows($result);



?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>IT Flower invoice</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style_popup.css" media="all" />
 <link href="assets/css/utopia-white.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

  <div class="invoice">
    <header class="clearfix">
      <div id="logo">
        <img src="assets/img/utopia-logo1.png">
      </div>
      <div id="company">
        <h2 class="name">Indian Traditional Flowers</h2>
        <div>10 - 3500 McNicoll Ave., <br>Toronto, Ontario ON M1V 4c7</div>
        <div>+1.647.836.9999</div>
        <div><a href="mailto:info@itflowers.com">info@itflowers.com</a></div>
      </div>

    </header>
    <main>
      <div id="details" class="clearfix">
        <div id="client">
          <div class="to">INVOICE TO:</div>
          <h2 class="name"><?php 
          $sql2=mysql_query("SELECT franchies, customer FROM sadmin_sales where invoice_no='".$invoice."'");
          $res1=mysql_fetch_array($sql2);echo $res1['customer']; 
          $franchies= $res1['franchies'];

          $sql3=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sadmin_customer where email='".$franchies."'");
           $res2=mysql_fetch_array($sql3);
          echo $res2['shop_name'];
          ?></h2>

         <div class="address"> <?php echo $res2['owner_name']; ?> </div>
          <div class="address"><?php echo $res2['address']; ?></div>
          <div class="email"><?php echo $res2['email']; ?></div>
             <div class="email"><?php echo $res2['phone']; ?></div>
        </div>
        <div id="invoice">
          <h1>INVOICE NO: <?php echo $invoice; ?></h1>
          <div class="date">Date of Invoice: <?php echo $date = date('d/m/Y h:i:s a'); ; ?></div>

        </div>
      </div>
      <table class="inventory" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <thead>
          <tr style="text-align: center;">
            <th class="no">#</th>
            <th class="desc">DESCRIPTION</th>
            <th class="unit">UNIT PRICE</th>
            <th class="qty">QUANTITY</th>
            <th class="total">TOTAL</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>

        <?php
        $tax=0;
        $ship=0;
        $paid=0;
        $bal=0;
        $grand=0;

        $sum=0;
        for($i=1; $i<$count;)
        {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {

        $franchies = $row['franchies'];

        echo "<td class='no'>".$i."</td> ";
        echo "<td class='desc'>" . $row['product_name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td class='unit'>" . $row['unit_price'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td class='qty'>" . $row['quantity'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td  class='total' >".$row['total']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>"; 
        $sum=$sum + $row['total'];
        $i++;
        //$tax=$sum *.13;
        $include=$row['tax_type'];

        if ($include =='includetax')
        { 
            $tax1=mysql_query("select * from sadmin_tax  where tax_type like 'include%'");
            $res1=mysql_fetch_array($tax1);
            $tax2=$res1['percentage'];
            $tax=$sum * $tax2/100;
            $sum1=$sum - $tax;

        } 
        else
        { 
            $tax3=mysql_query("select * from sadmin_tax  where tax_type like 'exclude%'");
            $res3=mysql_fetch_array($tax3);
            $tax4=$res3['percentage'];
            $tax=$sum * $tax4/100;
            $sum1=$sum + $tax;

        }

        $ship=$row['shipping_amt'];
        $paid=$row['paid_amt'];

        $grand=$sum1 + $ship;
        $bal=$grand - $paid;

        }
        }
        ?>



        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
            <td colspan="2">SUBTOTAL</td>
            <td>$ <?php echo $sum; ?></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
            <td colspan="2">TAX 13%</td>
            <td>$ <?php echo $tax; ?></td>
          </tr>
            <tr>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
            <td colspan="2">SHIP</td>
            <td>$<?php echo $ship; ?></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
            <td colspan="2">PAID</td>
            <td>$<?php echo $paid; ?></td>
          </tr>
           <tr>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
            <td colspan="2">BALANCE</td>
            <td>$<?php echo $bal; ?></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
            <td colspan="2">GRAND TOTAL</td>
            <td>$<?php echo $grand; ?></td>

          </tr>

        </tfoot>
      </table>
<button onclick="myFunction()" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 106px;float: right;">Print this page</button>

     <!--  <div id="thanks">Thank you!</div>
      <div id="notices">
        <div>NOTICE:</div>
        <div class="notice">A finance charge of 1.5% will be made on unpaid balances after 30 days.</div>
      </div>
    </main>
    <footer>
      Invoice was created on a computer and is valid without the signature and seal.
    </footer> -->
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    window.print();
}
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you want only one row or multiple rows

Comment: on which line there is the actual error/ not showing any rows?

Comment: it based on where clause condition, ex: invoice_no="'.$invoiceno.'", multiple products have same invoice_no or single product have single invoice_no.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain I understand your question fully, are you saying you have multitple rows but only want one?

If so , check out MySQL "LIMIT " which will limit your SQL query to X number of rows, such as `SELECT * FROM sadmin_customer where email='".$franchies." LIMIT 1`

This will return only 1 row, the first row where the conditions are true.